# How to configure Eclipse with CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've been trying to use CDT with Eclipse 3.4 under Windows XP with cygwin.

What do I need to do, in order to get startet?
I used "eclipse-cpp-ganymede-SR1-win32.zip" found on the Eclipse homepage.

Edit:

The main problem is, that I cannot compile and run the code.

In the run configuration, I tried gcc.exe for the C/C++ Application:

After adding the path of make.exe to my $Path, and starting from scratch, it works perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the contents of your make file. Could you post its contents?

Comment: It was a problem with the $Path. Solved.

Comment: Please add your solution to an answer and not as an edit to your post. That way you can accept your own answer (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found. Thanks guys.

After downloading and unpacking "eclipse-cpp-ganymede-SR1-win32.zip", you need to install either Cygwin or MinGW.

Make sure the compiler (e.g. gcc.exe) and make.exe is on your $Path.

Start Eclipse and everything should work fine.

Comment: As a note, I had trouble because I had not installed "make". If others are reading the above answer I recommend to them getting on that command line and typing the commands "gcc" "g++" and "make" to make sure that these tools, which CDT will use, are available. The major symptom of not having make was that Eclipse didn't automatically include the system header paths in my new project, so Eclipse didn't even know that stdio.h was a valid header.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Eclipse/CDT on Windows, you should consider using [Wascana Desktop Developer](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/), a CDT distro specially targeting Windows hosts.

Answer (score 1):

According the the [CDT Downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php):

> As a minimum, you need to install the Eclipse Platform Runtime before installing the CDT

So adding the [CDT Ganymede update site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/ganymede/) to your current eclipse 3.4 configuration should be enough for you to install CDT.

After that, do you have any error message ?

For instance, there can be some [eclipse.ini-related issues](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg26763.html) when using this package.

Comment: This package really is much easier to install through the update site.

Answer (score 0):

For me the package you downloaded worked from start. However I was using it with MinGW instead of Cygwin.

I am using it also for QT4 development together with QT Integrator.

Answer (score 0):

I use MinGW, though I note that the [documentation says you can use Cygwin](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm). I would have a look through [Max Berger's CDT guide](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/) to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can install both Cygwin and MinGW in your system. gcc and make available with Mingw seems to be suitable better for native windows build. If the PATH environment is set to paths of Cygwin [and/or] MinGW Eclipse project wizard asks you select one . Either Cygwin or MinGW.

For MingW, you may need to download gdb as well, if you need to debug your application